# jQuery ajax beforeSend shadows the `$.ajaxSetup` one, How to cascade it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework.

And I have to add the `X-CSRFToken` header before every jquery ajax send.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});
```

So, everything is well until I make a ajax call with an beforeSend setting given:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '...',
    data: { ... },
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        // This function do shadows the ajaxSetup one.
    }
});
```

So, is there any efficient way to cascade the beforeSend processors on the `jQuery.ajaxSetup` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, in the jQuery document of [jQuery Event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/), setting the `beforeSend` from the `$.ajax` call or `$.ajaxSetup` is called a **Local Event**, but in the current case, using a `$(document).ajaxSend()` which is called a **Global Event** is much more suitable.

---

## Final solution

In the case if you want to add multiple global event processor on ajax send, do not set it on `$.ajaxSetup`.

#### Use the `ajaxSend` event instead!

`http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/`

So the code may look like:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !settings.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If defining a new `beforeSend` inject in `$.ajaxSetup`, I can cascade the other ones defined in previous `$.ajaxSetup`:

```
(function() {
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    var originBeforeSend = jQuery.ajaxSettings.beforeSend;
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            // Call the previous beforeSend processor first.
            if(originBeforeSend && originBeforeSend(xhr, settings) === false) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

But anyway, if I specified another `beforeSend` in `$.ajax()` call, this way has not luck. It was still shadowed.